# NodeJs route not working

Tags: node.js, api, express

I am new to NodeJs. I am getting error with below code.

```
    var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    port = process.env.PORT || 9090,
    mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Cheque = require('./models/cheque'),
    router = express.Router();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

mongoose.connect('http://localhost:27017/utils/chequeman');

router.route('/cheques').post(function (req, res) {
    console.log('u r in cheques.');
    var cheque = new Cheque();
    cheque.chequeReceiptDate = req.body.chequeReceiptDate;

    cheque.save(function (err) {
        if (err)
            res.send(err)

        res.json({ message: 'Cheque details added' });
    });
});


app.use('/api', router);
app.listen(port);
console.log('Magin happens at' + port);
```

---

When I am trying POST request in postman I am getting response as "Cannot POST /api/cheques"

Please help.

Comment: Your code is fine, could you show a screen shot from postman

Comment: There is no issue with your code, i even checked in `postman`, everything is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try to declare the variables that you are using.

```
let express = require('express');
let app = express();
let bodyParser = require('body-parser');
let port = process.env.PORT || 9090;
let mongoose = require('mongoose');
let Cheque = require('./models/cheque');
let router = express.Router();
```

Take your API static

`app.use('/CHEQUEDIRECTORY', express.static(__dirname + '/CHEQUEDIRECTORY'))`

Don't forget to export modules on you API.

Have you installed the packages correctly?

Comment: Your variables declaration is not correct, you shoud use `;` instead of `,`

Comment: Yes, I just copy his code and forget to fix this.Well minded